# Consulta de Actualización de un campo con datos de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla master y la tabla detalle

```
Master
inv_id
inv_number
inv_totalCost

Detalle
idt_id
idt_invMasterNumber
idt_productId
idt_quantity
idt_productUnitCost
idt_productTotalCostItem
```

hay una relación de uno a muchos

`master.inv_number -> detalle.idt_invMasterNumber`

Necesito actualizar el campo `master.inv_totalCost` con la **suma** de `detalle.idt_productTotalCostItem` de todos los registros que cumplan la condicion `master.inv_number = detalle.idt_invMasterNumber`

Gracias por su valiosa ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Hola puede usar una consulta SELECT - UPDATE

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = ''
```

En tu caso por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.inv_totalCost = SUM(Table_B.idt_productTotalCostItem)    
FROM
    Master AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN detalle AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.inv_number  = Table_B.idt_invMasterNumber
GROUP BY Table_A.inv_number
```

Elimine el where por que realmente el INNER JOIN ya hace el filtro, pero eventualmente podrías usar un where para agregar más condiciones a la consulta.

Puedes ver mas información sobre este tipo de consultas aquí: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/

Comment: Tu enlace hace referencia  sql server pero el OP en sus etiquetas indica MySQL, sirve también?

Comment: Josue, gracias por el ejemplo, pero la consulta no funciona, en alguna parte se debe de agrupar por `Table_B.idt_invMasterNumber` y el `FROM` no lo recibe el workbench.

Comment: Hola, si en el fondo todos los motores de base de datos relacionales (Sql Server, MySql, Oracle..) utilizan sentencias ANSI SQL, y esta que te menciona funciona en varios motores de bases de datos. Este otro enlace (en ingles) te da una perspectiva del mismo query aplicado con sintaxis MySql propiamente, sin embargo podrías usar la que te mencione. Este es el link que te menciono: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: Listo, actualicé la respuesta. Para que la suma se agrupe por Table_A.inv_number.

Answer (score 1):

La consulta queda asi:

```
UPDATE master 
SET 
    inv_totalCost = (SELECT 
            SUM(idt_productTotalCost) AS sum_of_idt_productTotalCost
        FROM
            detail
        WHERE
            master.inv_id = detail.idt_invMasterId)
```

A Josue, Gracias por su orientación

Comment: Excelente, puntua la respuesta para poder ayudar a otros. Saludos desde Costa Rica